# Compiler says missing return statement but I already have 3

Tags: java

This is just weird. My compiler says I am missing a return statement, but I already have 3.
Here is my code:

```
public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    int i = tGen();
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
    {
        int fastplod = 3;
        return fastplod;
    }

    if (i >= 6 && i <= 8)
    {
        int slowplod = 1;
        return slowplod;
    }

    if (i >= 9 && i <= 10)
    {
        int slip = -6;
        return slip;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what should be returned if _none_ of the _if_ conditions is true?

Comment: if i == 11 it will hit no return statement

Comment: What happens if `i < 1` or `i > 10`?

Comment: In this situation: i > 10, which of your return statements will execute.  Hint: none.

Comment: But I have a generator that makes a number from 1 to 10

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that, when it compiles this method.

Comment: @user3670333 if you know that your code should be one of those three cases, put each case into an `if/else`, and the make your last `else` some kind of error handler. Maybe throw an exception or return an error code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make sure that there is **always** a value returned. If all your conditions fail you don't return anything.

A fix would be to chain your `if` statements because they are exclusive and use a `else` to catch all other cases.

```
public int tortoiseMoves() {
    int i = tGen();
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
    {
        int fastplod = 3;
        return fastplod;
    }

    else if (i >= 6 && i <= 8)
    {
        int slowplod = 1;
        return slowplod;
    }

    else if (i >= 9 && i <= 10)
    {
        int slip = -6;
        return slip;
    }
    else {
        // return something or throw exception
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would definitely go with the throwing the exception option on this one, anything else could lead to difficult to detect bugs later on

Comment: @RichardTingle feel free to edit the post with the exception you feel is appropriate.

Comment: To be honest with exceptions that I think "Are never going to come up" I just throw a runtime exception. If it happens its a programming mistake I need to fix and I just need to be made aware of it. Given that it should never happen and this is just a fall back it's not worth putting more thought into it than that

Comment: @RichardTingle We don't know where the method `tGen()` gets the value from. Could also be external and not under his control.

Comment: you are right,  I am making assumptions based on the comments from the OP that they have "covered all possible values" but what that exactly means isn't 100% clear

Answer (score 7):

There has to be at least one return statemant that will surley be reached, but there is no such statement in your code

Comment: but there is 3 returns in my if loops

Comment: But it can be the case that no one ever executes

Comment: And if i > 10 or i < 1, what gets returned?

Comment: if tGen() returns -1 none of your i conditions is met, thus nothing would be returned if you wouldn't add a fourth return statement outsdide your if statements

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a return statement for every possible case in the code. It can be a case in which all the `ifs` evaluate to `false` and hence, no `return` statement will execute. Try this:

```
public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    int i = tGen();
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
    {
        int fastplod = 3;
        return fastplod;
    }

    if (i >= 6 && i <= 8)
    {
        int slowplod = 1;
        return slowplod;
    }

    if (i >= 9 && i <= 10)
    {
        int slip = -6;
        return slip;
    }

    return Something to return if none of the ifs is true
}
```

Althought you can change the code to this:

```
public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    int i = tGen();
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
    {
        int fastplod = 3;
        return fastplod;
    } else if (i >= 6 && i <= 8){
        int slowplod = 1;
        return slowplod;
    } else if (i >= 9 && i <= 10) {
        int slip = -6;
        return slip;
    } else {
        return Something if none of the ifs is true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to avoid this problem in general:

The default return:

```
public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    int i = tGen();
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
    {
        int fastplod = 3;
        return fastplod;
    }

    if (i >= 6 && i <= 8)
    {
        int slowplod = 1;
        return slowplod;
    }

    if (i >= 9 && i <= 10)
    {
        int slip = -6;
        return slip;
    }

    //If code reaches here, you know none of the other returns were called
    return someDefaultValue;
    // OR
    // throw new Exception("Invalid value generated by tGen(): " + i);

}
```

Or the if/else

```
public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    int i = tGen();
    if (i >= 1 && i <= 5)
    {
        int fastplod = 3;
        return fastplod;
    }
    else if (i >= 6 && i <= 8)
    {
        int slowplod = 1;
        return slowplod;
    }
    else //Code is guaranteed to reach here and return if the previous if statements fail
    {
        int slip = -6;
        return slip;
        // OR
        // throw new Exception("Invalid value generated by tGen(): " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is to end with a `throw`, if reaching the end of the method is an indication that something has happened that is not supposed to happen.

Comment: what if their cant be a default

Comment: Do what @ajb says and throw an exception in the last else, or at the last statement. If you know the value has to be in one of your `if` statements, then you want your program to notify you if something unexpected happens.

Answer (score 2):

Simple, if all the if statements are false the code doesn't know what to return!

I don't know if this is a better solution for your case:

```
public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    switch (tGen())
    {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5: return 3; // slowplod
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8: return 1; // fastplod
        case 9:
        case 10: return -6; // slip
        default: return 0; // default value if not in range
    }
}
```

Solution 2 (lookup table): //fastest without using switch or branching with if

```
public int tortoiseMoves()
{
    int[] moves = {3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,-6,-6};
    return moves[tGen()-1];
}
```

Be careful of ArrayOutOfBondException!

Comment: It can't compile because **every** method needs to return a value if it's not void, in this case is integer so you need to return something outside the if statements

Comment: ahh. That makes more sense

Answer (score 2):

Only one of your `if(...)` statements can be true for a given run of the function. Therefore, it will probably be more clear to use `if/if else/else` structure. You could put the `return` or `throw` statement outside the `if` structure, but I think putting it in the `else` makes it more clear.

```
public int tortoiseMoves() {
    int i = tGen();                         // random: 1 <= i <= 10
    if      (i >= 1 && i <= 5)  return 3;   // fastplod
    else if (i >= 6 && i <= 8)  return 1;   // slowplod
    else if (i >= 9 && i <= 10) return -6;  // slip
    else throw new IllegalStateException(); // this shouldn't happen!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning:** many of the comments suggest that your error is due to not telling the compiler what to do for ALL conditions. However, it's important to realize that even if you cover ALL possible conditions with `if`/`if else` the compiler will still complain.

```
public boolean isPositive(int x){
    if(x > 0)        return true;
    else if(x <= 0)  return false;
    // error: "This method must return a result of type boolean"
}
```

In this case the compiler technically has enough information to determine that one of the above statements must be true because `x ∈ ℤ = {x | x ≤ 0} ⋃ {x | x > 0}`. However, you'll still need the last `return` either inside an `else` or outside the `if` structure.